# Need help with partitions after dual booting ubuntu to existing windows 10 install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, fdisk, parted

I was given an older Compaq Presario CQ60 Laptop with Windows 10 on it and I setup a dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.  I'm a linux beginner and was way over my head with the install but everything is working.  In my endevor to learn terminal and the different partitioning commands, lsblk, fdisk, sfdisk and parted, I have found I have some partition issues and I don't know what to do.  It seems there was an old windows 8 partition I was not aware of when I did the installation.

**Using the command sudo parted -l gives the output:**

```
wildman@wildman-Compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo parted -l  
[sudo] password for wildman:   
Model: ATA ST320LT020-9YG14 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB  

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags  
 1      1049kB  246GB  246GB   primary   ntfs            boot  
 2      246GB   262GB  16.1GB  primary   ext4  
 3      262GB   310GB  48.3GB  extended                  lba  
 5      262GB   308GB  46.2GB  logical   ext4  
 6      308GB   310GB  2146MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)  
 4      310GB   320GB  9707MB  primary   ntfs
```

**The command lsblk gives the following output**

```
wildman@wildman-Compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ lsblk  
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  
loop0    7:0    0  54.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1055  
loop1    7:1    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74  
loop2    7:2    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/95  
loop3    7:3    0  35.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198  
loop4    7:4    0  42.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313  
loop5    7:5    0   8.4M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/81  
loop6    7:6    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100  
loop7    7:7    0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/296  
loop8    7:8    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6350  
loop9    7:9    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/90  
loop10   7:10   0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61  
loop11   7:11   0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67  
loop12   7:12   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45  
loop13   7:13   0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/292  
loop14   7:14   0   8.4M  1 loop /snap/nmap/249  
loop15   7:15   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260  
loop16   7:16   0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/63  
loop17   7:17   0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406  
loop18   7:18   0    16M  1 loop /snap/communitheme/1768  
loop19   7:19   0 180.2M  1 loop /snap/spotify/35  
loop20   7:20   0  88.5M  1 loop /snap/core/7270  
loop21   7:21   0  54.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1049  
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk   
├─sda1   8:1    0   229G  0 part   
├─sda2   8:2    0    15G  0 part /  
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part   
├─sda4   8:4    0     9G  0 part   
├─sda5   8:5    0    43G  0 part /home  
└─sda6   8:6    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]  
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

**and lastly using the command sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sda gives the following output**

```
wildman@wildman-Compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sda  
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disklabel type: dos  
Disk identifier: 0x8f3b2f58  

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type  
/dev/sda1  *         2048 480351524 480349477  229G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda2       480352256 511809535  31457280   15G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda3       511811582 606183423  94371842   45G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)  
/dev/sda4       606183424 625142447  18959024    9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda5       511811584 601989119  90177536   43G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda6       601991168 606183423   4192256    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris  


If I understand correctly Windows 10 is on sda1  
before the install I shrank the partition into three parts for root, home, and swap.  
sda2 should be root for Ubuntu
Sda5 should be home for Ubuntu
sda6 should be swap for Ubuntu

That leave sda3 which is 45 GB W98 Ext'd (LBA) and sda4 which is 9 GB HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

What do I do about that? Please Help.

Comment: http://www.linfo.org/extended_partition.html

Comment: As link says the extended partition is just a container for the logical partitions, it should be approximately the sum of all your logical partitions if fully used. With Windows 10 in BIOS boot mode be sure to have Windows 10 repair disk and Ubuntu live installer available at all times. Windows will turn on fast start up which sets hibernation flag. And then grub will not boot it and you have to make Windows repairs.

Comment: The instructions to setup the dual boot had me turn off fast startup. How do I go about dealing with sda3 and sda4? I'm sure the "Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.  Partition table entries are not in disk order."  is bad. I went looking into the partitions because Ubuntu is running slow. Do I deal with these partitions in Linux, Windows, or Grub?  I'm completely lost in Grub.  Other than being slow the machine runs fine, boots to the Grub menu.  I just changed it to have Windows 10 listed first.  I haven't even rebooted since I did that.  I'm going to reboot now.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for the link, seriously. The problem is I'm even more confused now.  After reading the definition of extended partition I'm guessing that the original install of win8 created the extended and since there can be only one it will have to be assigned to the win10 primary partition, if that can even be done.  Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: @JohnHarvey Your partitions look totally fine, don't touch them. That the partition table entries are not in disk order is not an issue but result of naming convention (primary partition are numberd from 1 to 4, logical partitions start with 5). `sda3` doesn' start on physical sector boundary is not an issue as well, it's the extended partition, you never write to or read from it, so no impact on performance. Don't try to fix things yhat are not broken!